# Re hardlink and old rsnapshot backups

Tags: backup, rsnapshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an easy way to replace duplicate files with hardlinks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3037/is-there-an-easy-way-to-replace-duplicate-files-with-hardlinks)

I changed my naming scheme on `rsnapshot` from `localhost` to my actual host name, unfortunately this 'caused hardlinks to not be made in the next backup. Is there any way that I can relink my backup so that I'm not wasting space on my backup drive?