# How to clean up my desktop?

Tags: linux, rhel, disk-usage, administration

Now, I see that my desktop running rhel 5.6 has run out of space. Now I need to clean it up. There must be some unintentional files adding up. What I would like to be able to do is list the files in descending size order in a clean way and see the culprits.

Comment: Less likely a solution, but you may have some duplicated files to remove. See [Is there an easy way to replace duplicate files with hardlinks?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3037/10412) for some tools.

Comment: The command find . | xargs ls -l | grep ^- | sort -k 5 -n helped to zero down some culprits..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing to try is `yum clean packages`. Have a look at **`man yum`** for more cleanup options.

Other things you could do are mostly cleaning your own downloaded files, logs etc., to which there' no general rule.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is to install and run [`baobap`](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/baobab/) or [`KDirStat`](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/) or the like. This would give you a visual graph of what is taking up space, together with file types. You can easily spot the problem and delete/uninstall things you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [ncdu](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) for similar purposes.