# how to find duplicate folders inside main folder

Tags: ubuntu, directory, duplicate, fdupes

I've moved a lot of files and folders from my old nas to my new smb share.
The problem is that someone made entire copies of nearly every folder on that thing. And I need the space.

I'm currently running `fdupes` in a screen and outputting everything to a file.
But this will give me a huge list of duplicate files, which I have to filter into duplicate folders.

Are there any existing utilities which can find matching folders?  Or can someone suggest a shell script that might do the job?

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: What is a main folder? Is that a direct parent folder for the duplicates? Or some folder higher up in the hierarchy somewhere above the duplicates like `/`? What does 'there' (in "there you have to specify" to?

Comment: the folder is /home/user/sambadata

Comment: fdupes will give you a list of duplicate files, separated into paragraphs (one paragraph per set of dupes).  Only YOU can decide which of those are "original" files that need to be kept, and which are duplicates to be deleted.  BTW, this is probably obvious, but if the person who made the copies put them all under the one directory (and that directory doesn't have any important non-dupe files), just delete that directory.

Comment: yeah, but the problem is that that person did that about every month for a few years long. It's pretty ugly.

Comment: FYI: http://askubuntu.com/questions/3865/how-to-find-and-delete-duplicate-files   and this may be of interest http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3037/is-there-an-easy-way-to-replace-duplicate-files-with-hardlinks (but take note of the discussionss about some of the drawbacks of replacing with hard links)

Comment: that's file based. I have used `fdupes-r -o output.txt` right now, and the resultis that I have a file containing the location of 1.06 million duplicate files. That's too much for me to find the folders themselves to manually remove one of the duplicates.

Comment: [rmlint](https://rmlint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) has an option to find duplicate dirs.  You will need to follow the installation instructions to compile from source since it's not (yet) in the ubuntu/debian repositories.  Then run `rmlint --types=dupedirs --progress <path>...`.  It will generate a shell script `rmlint.sh` which you can then inspect and/or run to delete the duplicate dirs.

Comment: thomas, you're a hero! If this works it'll be a miracle